# Creating a list from CSV File

Tags: python, list, csv, header, dataset

I have dataset called "Investor History". I want to create a list from the following dataset using the csv package manually (without using the Panda Dataframe). The dataset has the following 3 headers:

```
Stock_Price          Exchange_Rate     Invest         
    High                 Low             Y
    High                 High            N       
    Low                  Low             Y
```

From that dataset, I want to create a list that seems like this as an output:

```
{('Stock_Price', 'High'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low'), ('Invest', 'Y')}
{('Stock_Price', 'High'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'High'), ('Invest', 'N')}
{('Stock_Price', 'Low'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low'), ('Invest', 'Y')}
```

it's more like printing the headers with the elements vertically.

Comment: you may read as normal list and later run own code to convert to tuples. Eventually check some `dialect` in csv which can gives as dictionares and later use `.items()` to get tuples.

Comment: in your example `{}` creates `set()` which doesn't have to keep order.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have real CSV with data separated by `,`

You can use `DictReader()` to get it as list of dictionares

```
f = open(filename)

reader = csv.DictReader(f)
rows = list(reader)
```

```
[
 {'Stock_Price': 'High', 'Exchange_Rate': 'Low', 'Invest': 'Y'},   
 {'Stock_Price': 'High', 'Exchange_Rate': 'High', 'Invest': 'N'}, 
 {'Stock_Price': 'Low', 'Exchange_Rate': 'Low', 'Invest': 'Y'}
]
```

And later you can use `.items()` to convert every dictionary into list of tuples

```
rows = [list(r.items()) for r in rows]
```

```
[
  [('Stock_Price', 'High'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low'), ('Invest', 'Y')],
  [('Stock_Price', 'High'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'High'), ('Invest', 'N')],
  [('Stock_Price', 'Low'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low'), ('Invest', 'Y')]
]
```

And if you really want as list of sets then you `set()` instead of `list()` -
but `set()` doesn't have to keep order

```
rows = [set(d.items()) for d in rows]
```

```
[
  {('Invest', 'Y'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low'), ('Stock_Price', 'High')},   
  {('Exchange_Rate', 'High'), ('Invest', 'N'), ('Stock_Price', 'High')},   
  {('Invest', 'Y'), ('Stock_Price', 'Low'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low')}
]
```

---

Full working example. I uses `io` only to simulate file.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

text  ='''Stock_Price,Exchange_Rate,Invest
High,Low,Y
High,High,N
Low,Low,Y'''


import io
f = io.StringIO(text)
#f = open(filename)

reader = csv.DictReader(f)
rows = list(reader)
pprint(rows)

rows1 = [list(d.items()) for d in rows]
pprint(rows1)

rows2 = [set(d.items()) for d in rows]
pprint(rows2)
```

Result:

```
[{'Exchange_Rate': 'Low', 'Invest': 'Y', 'Stock_Price': 'High'},
 {'Exchange_Rate': 'High', 'Invest': 'N', 'Stock_Price': 'High'},
 {'Exchange_Rate': 'Low', 'Invest': 'Y', 'Stock_Price': 'Low'}]

[[('Stock_Price', 'High'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low'), ('Invest', 'Y')],
 [('Stock_Price', 'High'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'High'), ('Invest', 'N')],
 [('Stock_Price', 'Low'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low'), ('Invest', 'Y')]]

[{('Invest', 'Y'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low'), ('Stock_Price', 'High')},
 {('Exchange_Rate', 'High'), ('Invest', 'N'), ('Stock_Price', 'High')},
 {('Invest', 'Y'), ('Stock_Price', 'Low'), ('Exchange_Rate', 'Low')}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it is simple. Use [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from Python.

Comment: Can you kindly give a solution to it?

Comment: I do not see your csv file therefore I can't detect its dialect correctly.
``` code-python
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
   spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   print([row for row in spamreader])
```
Inside loop it uses List Comprehensions (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Do you want to get a set, a dictionary, a list or a tuple of data from file?

Comment: I want a set. My CSV file is real CSV data separated by ",". After reading the data using open() function, I was wondering how to print the rows and header in above mentioned way!